# git: update HEAD after fetch into a bare repo

Tags: git

I have a bare repo at, say, /var/lib/repos/myrepo.git, I try to update it by doing:

```
$ cd /var/lib/repos/myrepo.git
$ git fetch
```

I get the latest commits from remote, however, the HEAD pointer is NOT updated.  If I do

```
$ git log
```

it just show me the log message BEFORE the update, if I do

```
$ git log FETCH_HEAD
```

I can see the latest commits.

I want to either update HEAD to point to the sha1 of FETCH_HEAD, or to let me clone the bare repo to another directory at FETCH_HEAD.   However, the FETCH_HEAD reference is NOT available in the working directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I have a bare repo**

In a bare repository, you **do not** have a file system so you don't have any ref to update.

> ... want to either update HEAD to point to the sha1 of FETCH_HEAD,

---

#### How to update the HEAD (which will be the default branch when cloning)

In a bare repo if you wish to set the default branch use this command:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<branch_name>
```

---

On a "regular" git repository you can do the following:

- Update your current branch to the desired commit:

  ```
  git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard
  ```
- Verify that the commit is fetched and exist in your local `.git` repo.
  Since you mentioned you can see the log of the commit so it should be in your repo

  ```
  git show FETCH_HEAD
  ```

Comment: It's a bare repo, so I think it should be `git reset FETCH_HEAD --soft` or `git update-ref HEAD FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: I accept either change the HEAD in the bare repo, or change it in the working directory.  The purpose is to get the latest code to compile.  So I cloned the code from the bare repo to another directory on the same machine.  I will experiment the solution tomorrow. thanks @CodeWizard

Comment: if you clone it use the reset, it will do the desired requesrt

Comment: I just found a potential problem in your description.  I have no problem selecting the branch, my problem is to set the pointer to the latest commit on that branch! @CodeWizard

Comment: the latest commit is origin/branch

Comment: ping here when u try it and ill. guide u how to

Comment: ill upfste the answer so others will benefit ftom it

Answer (score 1):

A clone made with `git clone --bare` has a default *empty* fetch refspec.  This means that when you run `git fetch`, you are effectively running `git fetch` with *no* refspec.  This is ... not a good plan.  A regular `--bare` repository is meant to be *pushed to*, and nothing else.

As [CodeWizard said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54744786/1256452), a bare clone has no work-tree, but this is something of a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  A bare clone still does have a `HEAD` reference, which is a symbolic reference pointing to one of its branch names.

You probably want a clone made with `git clone --mirror`.  This is the same as a bare clone except that its default fetch refspec is `+refs/*:refs/*`.  This means that running `git fetch` in such a clone updates *all* of its references to match the upstream repository, unconditionally.

Note that this kind of clone is *not* meant for receiving `git push` requests, because running `git fetch` within it will *replace* **all** of its branch name to hash-ID mappings with whatever is set in its `origin`.

If, however, you want a bare clone that updates whichever branch its `HEAD` maps to, you can:

- find out which branch its `HEAD` is a symbolic ref *to*, using `git branch --symbolic-ref HEAD`
- run `git fetch origin +refs/heads/name:refs/heads/name` to update that one reference.

Or if you won't re-assign `HEAD` in this repository, you could run:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

(assuming the `HEAD` name resolves to `master`), after which a plain `git fetch` will update just the master branch.

Comment: I have tried the above solution and find what worked.  My situation is that the bare repo is a cache of the remote repo on a builder machine, simply for the sake of speed.   While a devops pipeline is triggered, I checkout code from the local bare repo, do the compile then remove the working directory.

Comment: If the purpose of this bare repository is to act as a cache for speed, look into reference clones. You can use `git clone --mirror` to make a local reference clone, then `git clone` from the upstream using `--reference` to point to the local reference clone.